# How to solve Expression.Error in this code

Tags: powerbi, m

I have this `M` code, where I try to set this condition: when `create_to_launch` contains char `d`, then I'll only take the first value of its string. But, when it does not contain it, I'll take the first 3. However I'm getting an error, and I cannot find it:

```
let

    #"Columna cambiada5" = Table.ReplaceValue( #"Columna cambiada4" ,each "create_to_launch",
    each if Text.Contains(_, "d") then Table.TransformColumns(#"Columna cambiada4", 
    {{"create_to_launch", each Text.Start(_, 1)}}) 
    else "create_to_launch", Table.TransformColumns(#"Columna cambiada4",{{"create_to_launch", 
    each Text.Start(_, 1)}}))

in  #"Columna cambiada5"

/* Error */
Expression.Error: Passed 4 arguments to a function that waits 5.
Details:
Pattern=
Arguments=[List]
```

Comment: Check your ReplaceValue;  you miss one argument (I think you miss replacer ). Make a fresh replace (from powerbi GUI and match your code)

Table.ReplaceValue(table as table, oldValue as any, newValue as any, replacer as function, columnsToSearch as list)

Comment: @msta42a and how could I do that if there are som if-else statements I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i create some dummy data

```
= Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if Text.Contains([Region], "d") then Text.Range([Region],0,1) else Text.Range([Region],0,3))
```

[image]